# importing svg and attaching event handlers in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

have an SVG file which I've imported as a component in my `+page.svelte` like this:

`import squares from '$lib/images/asset1.svg';`

The SVG that's imported looks like this:

```
<svg id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 230.29 105.89">
        <defs>
          <style>
            .cls-1 {
              fill: #451314;
            }
      
            .cls-1, .cls-2 {
              stroke: #231f20;
              stroke-miterlimit: 10;
            }
      
            .cls-2 {
              fill: #f58020;
            }
          </style>
        </defs>
        <g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1">
          <rect id="data1" class="cls-1" x=".5" y=".5" width="104.89" height="104.89"/>
          <rect id="data2" class="cls-1" x=".5" y=".5" width="104.89" height="104.89"/>
          <rect id="data3" class="cls-1" x=".5" y=".5" width="104.89" height="104.89"/>
          <rect class="cls-2" x="129.85" y=".5" width="99.94" height="104.89"/>
        </g>
      </svg>
```

I'm trying to make the SVG document interactive by attach an `onclick` event handlers to each of the `id's`.

What's the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should **not** attach click event handlers to non-interactive elements, as that is not keyboard accessible. Usually click handlers should be on `<button>` elements, but in SVGs that is not commonly easily integrated.

Many events bubble up the DOM tree, so here I would recommend adding *both* `on:click` and `on:keydown` on a wrapper element and checking the `target` of the event to see what element it came from. To make keyboard interaction work, the elements that should be clickable also need to be focusable ([`tabindex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/tabindex)).

The import of the SVG also has to be changed to import the content, not a URL to the asset, so the HTML can be inserted into the document. E.g.

```js
import squares from '$lib/images/asset1.svg?raw'; // note suffix

function onClick(e) {
  if (e.target.id == '...') {
    // ...
  }
}
function onKeyDown(e) {
  // analogous logic to onClick, but check if `Enter` (and no modifier) was pressed
}
```

```html
<div on:click={onClick} on:keydown={onKeyDown}>
  {@html squares}
</div>
```

[REPL example](https://svelte.dev/repl/dd052eb6b89e4c21b47c59caa46cf929?version=3.55.1)

---

Note that SVGs are valid Svelte. So if you do not need the SVG for anything else, you can just change the extension and import it as a component instead.

You then can handle events directly on the respective elements and [dispatch](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-createeventdispatcher) to the parent component or forward events (just `on:event` without handler).

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for. The only variant is that I'm using the Skeleton UI libs, specifically the popup util https://www.skeleton.dev/utilities/popups. This needs to add a `use:popup={exampleCombobox}` to the element instead of the alert. Which bit would need to change to use this instead? Basically want to use the popup instead of an alert.

Comment: Please ask a separate question, this is out of scope and highly specific to the library. (This uses an action and not an event handler directly, so it can't be handled the same way at all.)

Comment: The question would be how use the `popup` action of that library with an element that is not directly accessible and to trigger it on a keyboard event. The answer is probably: *You can't*. The library API design is questionable to say the least.

Comment: OK thanks - I shall do that.

Comment: One more detail, SVG positioning is vastly different from regular HTML layout. The library is probably not designed to handle that so it may not work if you intend to show a popup at the SVG element's location. You might have to look for a library that can actually handle that.

Comment: Thanks - good to know. I think I might just use a modal instead here.